# Magento - How is the recently_compared template removed from the layout when it is not needed?

Tags: magento

The following layout file contains 2 blocks, which reference the product_viewed.phtml and product_compared.phtml templates.
    \app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\reports.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <!-- Mage_Reports -->
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
            <block type="reports/product_compared" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.compared" template="reports/product_compared.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I put a log at the top of each template.
If there are no recently compared products, the product_compared.phtml template is not even processed. ie. no log.

(To make the recently compared template appear (product_compared.phtml), you need to compare a product, then click 'Clear All' from the 'compare product' template)

So I assume the recently compared template is being removed programatically? Where is this happening?

Also, if I change the name of the block, it is still not processed. So if the block's name isn't used to get a reference to it, how is it being referenced so it can be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I assume the recently compared template is being removed programmatically? Where is this happening?

That's a reasonable assumption, but it's not *quite* how things are done in Magento.  Magento renders templates with block objects.  The block objects usually contain the sort of logic you're looking for.

In your case the block is a `reports/product_viewed` block.  That means the class used to instantiate the object which renders that block is  `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed`

[image: Commerce Bug's Alias Lookup Tab]

Blocks are rendered via their `_toHtml` method.  So, if we take a look at the `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed` block's `_toHtml` method we'll see the following

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Viewed.php
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getCount()) {
        return '';
    }
    $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

So, if this block's `getCount` method returns `not true`, the `_toHtml` method will return and empty string.  The block will never call the `parent::_toHtml()` method, and it's this method which renders the block's template.

You can trace the code from `getCount` in this and the parent `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract` class to determine why, exactly, this happens.  In general terms though, `getCount` returns 0 if there's no items to display, and therefore the block renders as empty.  There's a similar thing happening in the `reports/product_compared` (or `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Compared`) block.

Comment: Strom.Thanks for solution.I was puzzle for 4hrs why recent retrieve  is not coming. +1 from me